# React Router and Nav.Link fail

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

Good day, I'm new to React and have some problems about the routes.

Here's a brief description of my code.

In the `App.js`, I imported a MemberPage :

```
    <Route path="/">
      <HomePage/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/member">
      <MemberPage/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/product">
      <ProductPage/>
    </Route>
```

i'd like to put more routes in MemberPage.

Here's my code in MemberPage.

I'd like to keep the membermenu and show userprofile or coupon when switching path, as you can see in picture1 below.

Not sure if it's the right way to do it, but it's working fine when i type the path in url myself.

```
<Router>
  <>
    <div className="container memberpage-container">
      <MemberMenu />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/member/userprofile">
          <Userprofile />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/member/coupon">
          <Coupon />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </>
</Router>
```

[image: picture1]

But there are some problems when i use the Nav.Link.

Here's my code in navbar:

```
 <li className="navBar-dropdown_item">
    <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/member/uerprofile">
     PROFILE
    </Nav.Link>
 </li>
                  
 <li className="navBar-dropdown_item">
    <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/member/coupon">
     COUPON
    </Nav.Link>
 </li>
```

**The problem is:**

When i click on the navbarItem to go to UserProfile page, it works.

However when i'm already at the UserProfile page, if i click the navbarItem to go to coupon page, the url did change but it's still staying at UserProfile page.(vice versa)

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: I see a syntax error here <Route exact path="/member/userprofile">, with  <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/member/uerprofile">

one is /userprofile and the second one you wrote /uerporifle, you forgot the s. Try to change it, if doesn't work please show your  whole router file

Comment: to DarioRega,  thank you for your reply. I just discovered that it was because I had a nested router. Problem solved when i removed the <Route></Route> in  MemberPage. Thank you again for your kind reply and have a great day :D